# using Kubernetes for better performance on REST API calls

Tags: rest, web-applications, kubernetes, orchestration

I'm part of a team for a financial web-app basically depending on SDK for the most part(pages normally take 5-10 seconds to load) running on a single Docker Container, would migrating it to Kubernetes or any other container Orchestration improve the response speed or performance of the APIs?
or is there any other ways to improving the response speed of the APIs?

Comment: APIs are from a financial application called Investran

Comment: You'd need to run a profiler on your backend to know where the time is going.  Running the same code with the same external dependencies on a different runtime is unlikely to change its performance characteristics.